# Query returns different result from phpmyadmin and webpage/

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb, myisam

I have a mysql query like below

```
SELECT count(id) as total, 
       MIN(product_price) as min_price, 
       MAX(product_price) as max_price 
FROM `products_details` 
WHERE     subcat_id = 425 
      AND MATCH(alternate_name, product_desc, keywords) AGAINST ('+gas  +(>lighter <lighters)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This query should be return count value as **7** as per the table records.

But when I executing this query using php in my website it is returning the count value as **59**.

When I ran this query directly to phpmyadmin I'm getting correct result.

Can anyone tell why I'm getting this kind of problem and how can I solve this.

**Note:** **When I changed this query like below in when I was ran in phpmyadmin I'm getting the wrong result 59.**

```
SELECT count(id) as total, 
       MIN(product_price) as min_price, 
       MAX(product_price) as max_price 
FROM `products_details` 
WHERE     subcat_id = 425 
      AND MATCH(alternate_name, product_desc, keywords) AGAINST ('+gas  +(&gt;lighter &lt;lighters)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The method of executing this query using php like below

```
if (!isset($connection))
            die('Database connection is not valid');

        $result         = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() . ' :: executeQuery');

        if (!$result)
            return;

        if (!@mysql_num_fields($result))
            return false;
        else {
            $result = $result;
        }

        if (!isset($result))
            die('Error in Query');
        else {
            $ret        = null;
            if ($object = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                $ret    = $object;
            }
            mysql_free_result($result);
            return $ret;
        }
```

Comment: Are you running the query through something like `mysql_real_escape_string()` that might change your query at all?

Comment: Could you add information how you run this query on your webpage?

Comment: The wrong result 59? But 59 is clearly the right result. I want 59.

Comment: No @James Paterson. we didn't change like this, we directly execute the query using mysql_query() function.

Comment: By the way use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`. Furthermore you could try to set the encoding to utf8: `mysqli_query($conn, "set names 'utf8'");`

Comment: @rbr94 , see my question i have added the method of executing this query.

Comment: @rbr94, Its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

`&gt;` is the "htmlentity" for `>`.  If `&gt;` is actually in the query, then it is unlikely to work as expected.  Decide where that is coming from and avoid it.